# Pointed to value does not change

Tags: c, arrays

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ara[]={1,2,3};
    int *pr=ara;
    printf("*pr |%d|\n",*pr);
    ara[0]=2;
    printf("*pr |%d|\n",*pr);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
*pr |1|
*pr |2|
```

In the code above the value of `*pr` changes from `1` to `2` after changing the first element of the array?

But in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ara[]={1,2,3};
    int x=ara[0];//value of x is now 1
    ara[0]=2;
    printf("x=%d\n",x);//value of x still remains 1
    return 0;
}
```

the value of x is not changed.

Why?

Comment: In second case `x` is just variable of type `int`, with no connection to `ara` array.

Comment: because `x` is a value type, not a reference type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this

```
int x=ara[0];
```

you tell the compiler that:

- You want to create a new, independent variable called `x` of type `int`, and
- The initial value of that variable must be copied from `ara[0]`.

From that point on, there is no relationship between `x` and `ara[0]`: changing one of them does not make the other one change.

When you work with a pointer, you also create an independent variable, but this time the variable keeps an address of some other value in memory (in addition to keeping a value of a pointer). When you talk about pointers, you distinguish between two values - the value of the pointer, and the value the pointer points to. In your first example, `ptr` keeps the original value, but the value that it points to is changed.

Comment: `x` is a strong independent variable who don't need no array!

Answer (score 2):

Because the variable `int x` is a symbol to an integer location in the memory. This location is separate from the memory location of `int ara[]`.

You should use a pointer `x` in order to point to the first element location of the array; this would reflect the modifications in the array. Using an asterix before the variable name makes it a pointer. This is why `int *pr` reflects the changes.

Btw the name of the array variable (`ara`) is the address of the first element in the array; practically the address of `ara[0]`. The line `int *pr = ara` makes the variable point to the first element memory location in the array.

Answer (score 2):

For first case

```
   int ara[]={1,2,3};
   int *pr=ara;
```

Here pointer `pr` pointed to address of first element of array `ara`. Now value at this address is `1` ( means `ara[0]=1`). Now you assign different value at this address by `ara[0]=2;`. So you will get expected output.

For second case.

```
 int ara[]={1,2,3};
 int x=ara[0];
```

here `x` variable with type `int` created and you assigned value of `ara[0]` to `x`. So it's basic value assignment. No connection between `ara[0]` and `x`. After changing value `ara[0]` variable `x` not modified.

Answer (score 0):

so what's wrong,it will remain one,**Read the comments in the code to know how its working**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ara[]={1,2,3};
    int x=ara[0];     //**value of x is now 1 which it is taking from arr[0]**
    ara[0]=2;          // **value of arr[0] is being changed(but not x is modified here,it still holds the same value i.e 1)**
    printf("x=%d\n",x);//value of x still remains 1
    return 0;
}
```

Both of them are different and are allocated different memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you access the original object through pointer. In the second case you make a copy of `ara[0]` and store it to `x`. Since it is a copy, modifications of `ara[0]` will not change `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is of type `int` while `ptr` is `int *` .So `x` and `ara[0]` are two differents variables stored in two differents spaces on memory
doing `x = ara[0]` changes the value of `x`to be the same as `ara[0]` but change this one will not affect the other.